# Software for seeing images pixel by pixel with boundary around each pixel

Tags: images, editing

Please suggest some open source/free software by which I can zoom the image and see the boundary around each pixel (for example if we have boundary around each pixel, I can count say horizontal pixels just by visually looking the picture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[paint.net](http://www.getpaint.net/) has that as a feature- just select the 'show grid when zoomed in' button